# Qt Websocket processing multiple requests at the same time

Tags: multithreading, websocket, qtwebsockets

My application is based on the Qt websocket example (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebsockets-echoserver-example.html). In my application around 20 users are connected to the websocket server and some are sending messages with some megabytes.

I noticed that while the websocket server is receiving the those large messages (which can take some seconds or minutes) it completely blocks/queues all other requests or connects from other clients.

Are there any recommended designs how this issues can be addressed? Thanks